# How can I have a border with a shadow only around the border and not around element?

Tags: html, css

My fiddle will tell you all but I need a border with shadow, now this is fine if I use an empty `div` with no height, and I use `box-shadow` property but am not getting this effect when my `div` contains some text...So is there any workaround for this? Do I need to add an empty element to achieve this type of effect?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hRh93/)

CSS

```
.what_i_want {
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    margin: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.how_i_achieve_the_above_here {
    margin: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="what_i_want"></div>
<div class="how_i_achieve_the_above_here">Vaibhav</div>
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  Just use an empty div to made the shadowed line.

Comment: @jfriend00 Am aware of that, am using this to underline my menu items, so I dont want an empty element just to do some sort of this effect

Comment: Why not?  Empty elements are used all the time for stuff like this.  There's nothing wrong with doing it that way if that's the easiest way to solve your problem.  You can also use only some border edges, but that doesn't look like what you want in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @jfriend00 What I wanted was not to increase the markup side, If I can do it with CSS ONLY than no use of HTML elements in here ;), I do use empty elements for sprites but I wanted to avoid for such a lil thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRh93/1/)

```
.how_i_achieve_the_above_here:after{
    position:absolute;
    content: '';
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    left:0;
    bottom:-2px;
}
```

Comment: aaaa I missed out the after thing :p

Comment: If using :after, make sure it's support matches the versions of IE you want to be compatible with.  No support in IE7, partial support in IE8.

Comment: I doubt that IE7/8 supports box-shadow, probably nothing would should up even if IE had support for :after

Comment: @OneTrickPony I don't support those primitive browsers ;) thanks

Answer (score 1):

won't box-shadow just put a shadow around the "box" around the words anyways?  Can't you just use a `<h1>` or `<p>` tag with 100% width and a bottom-border with a shadow?  Not tested, but seems it should work.